# What is the name of this acro yoga move?

Tags: yoga

What is this [acro yoga move](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOAc8yn6qec) called, where the base is standing bent at the waist, the flyer stands next to them and leaps onto the shoulder of the base, while the base supports and lifts them with both hands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Reddit, it's called [shoulder bird](https://www.reddit.com/r/AcroYoga/comments/4fkmlm/what_is_the_name_of_this_acro_yoga_move/).